# Aggregate the given data frame based on the specific conditions in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df as shown below
df:

```
ID    Number_of_Cars    Age_in_days   Total_amount   Total_N     Type
1     2                 100           10000          100         A
2     5                 10            1000           2           B
3     1                 1000          1000           200         B
4     1                 20            0              0           C
5     3                 1000          100000         20          A
6     6                 100           10000          20          C
7     4                 200           10000          200         A
```

from the above df I would like to prepare df1 as shown below

df1:

```
ID    Avg_Monthly_Amount      Avg_Monthly_N  Type
1     3000                    30             A
2     3000                    6              B
3     30                      6              B
4     0                       0              C
5     3000                    0.6            A
6     3000                    6              C
7     1500                    30             A
```

Explanation:

```
Avg_Monthly_Amount = Avg monthly amount 
Avg_Monthly_N = Avg monthly N
```

To prepare df1, I tried below code

```
df['Avg_Monthly_Amount'] = df['Total_amount'] / df['Age_in_days'] * 30
df['Avg_Monthly_N'] = df['Total_N'] / df['Age_in_days'] * 30
```

From df and df1 (or df alone) I would like to prepare below dataframe as df2

I could not a write a proper code to generate below df2

Explanation:

Aggregate above number at Type level

Example:

```
There are 3 customers (ID = 1, 5, 7) with Type = A, hence for Type = A, Number_Of_Type  = 3
Avg_Cars for Type = A, is (2+3+4)/3 = 3
Avg_age_in_years for Type = A is ((100+1000+200)/3)/365
Avg_amount_monthly for Type = A is Mean of Average_Monthly_Amount in for type = A in df1 
Avg_N_monthly for Type = A is Mean of Avg_Monthly_N in for type = A in df1
```

Final expected output (df2)

```
Type  Number_Of_Type  Avg_Cars     Avg_age_in_years   Avg_amount_monthly    Avg_N_monthly
A     3               3            1.19               2500                  20.2
B     2               3            1.38               1515                  6
C     2               3.5          0.16               1500                  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't prepare other `df` named `df1` from your original dataframe `df`

your dataframe `df`:-

```
ID    Number_of_Cars    Age_in_days   Total_amount   Total_N     Type
1     2                 100           10000          100         A
2     5                 10            1000           2           B
3     1                 1000          1000           200         B
4     1                 20            0              0           C
5     3                 1000          100000         20          A
6     6                 100           10000          20          C
7     4                 200           10000          200         A
```

After you created/imported `df`:-

```
df['Avg_Monthly_Amount'] = df['Total_amount'] / df['Age_in_days'] * 30
df['Avg_Monthly_N'] = df['Total_N'] / df['Age_in_days'] * 30
df['Age_in_year']=df['Age_in_days']/365
```

Then:-

```
df2=df.groupby('Type').agg({'Type':'count','Number_of_Cars':'mean','Age_in_year':'mean','Avg_Monthly_Amount':'mean','Avg_Monthly_N':'mean'}).rename(columns={'Type':'Number_Of_Type'})
```

Now if you print or write `df2`(if you are using jupyter notebook) then you get your desired output

**Output:-**

```
    Number_Of_Type  Number_of_Cars  Age_in_year     Avg_Monthly_Amount  Avg_Monthly_N
Type                    
A             3           3.0        1.187215          2500.0             20.2
B             2           3.0        1.383562          1515.0             6.0
C             2           3.5        0.164384          1500.0             3.0
```

Comment: Can you please share your output

Comment: sure...I edited my answer just have a look.......btw if this solution helps you then feel free to accept the answer